# Android: new Google Client API Location

Tags: android, android-location

**Case:** application needs device location for specifying web request. If location providers disabled, it should use last known location. As `android.location` [seems to be deprecated in favor of Fused location API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), I decided to use new API but encountered some issues. With use of old API my case looks something like this:

```
//get Location
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
...
bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //check providers. If providers disabled, use last known location 
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000 * 60, 100, this);
    } else {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to make similar actions in Fused API. How availability of providers looks in the new API? Because new interfaces for Fused Location(`GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener`) don't give me a hint.

What I'm trying to understand is the use-case described in my post. *If location providers disabled, it should use last known location.* So, conditional statement in core location API for such case was result of `isProviderEnabled()` method. But what about new API?

Answer (score 2):

First, LocationManager is not deprecated. But it uses the Android API directly. The Google Fused Location is dependant on Google API (Not Android API, it means not all mobiles have it by default).

In Google API, you don't worry about which provider to use. But all you need is to connect to the API, register callbacks, send requests, and that is all.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

From several Google Developer documents:

This is to be put in your app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
}
```

In your activity, something like this should be put

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
         .addApi(LocationServices.API)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
         .build()
```

mGoogleApiClient must be declared as GoogleApiClient
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

Of course, this activity must implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, this has two functions onConnected and onConnectionSuspended.

Also implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener. This has a function OnConnectionFailed

In OnConnectionFailed, handle the failure (e.g. AlertDialog saying that there was an error in connection with Google API Services)

In OnConnection, you could put something like this

```
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().setInterval(1000 * 60);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Note for this, the activity must implement com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

This is one way, another way is to use PendingIntent to bind with BroadcastReceiver (more performance but the listener method could be ok)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this part is clear for me. What I'm trying to understand is the use-case described in my post. _If location providers disabled, it should use last known location._  So, conditional statement in core location API for such case was result of `isProviderEnabled()` method. But what about new API?